Show/hide based on select value Vuejs
I am trying to show/hide a div based on a select option (Eventually, I will query a database for existing values and write values when updated, but I'm trying to get this basic part working first). I am incorporating the code into an existing PHP page. Neither the divs are working, nor the text display {{ arrivalMethod }}. Thanks!
<?php
?>

<div id="method">
    <form>
        <p>Arrival Method:</p>
        <select v-model="arrivalMethod">
            <option value="bus">Bus</option>
            <option value="pickup">Plane</option>
            <option value="fly">Train</option>
        </select>
        <span>Selected: {{ arrivalMethod }}</span>
        <template>
            <div v-if="arrivalMethod === bus">
                <p>Taking the bus</p>
            </div>
            <div v-if="arrivalMethod === plane">
                <p>Taking the train</p>
            </div>
        </template>
        </form>
</div>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.js"></script>

<script>
    const app = Vue.createApp({
        data() {
            return {
                arrivalMethod:
            }
    })
    app.mount('#app')
</script>


you need to quote your literal values

Your three errors here are setting the default value for arrivalMehtod , mounting on app and as one of the comments suggested, the string comparison in the template tag needs to be enclosed within ''
Error #1:
data() {
  return {
    arrivalMethod: 'bus'
  }
}

Error #2:
Either in the HTML, div id should be app (preferable)
or in the script mount statement, id should be method
Error #3:
<template>
  <div v-if="arrivalMethod === 'bus'">
    <p>Taking the bus</p>
  </div>
  <div v-if="arrivalMethod === 'pickup'">
    <p>Taking the plane</p>
  </div>
  <div v-if="arrivalMethod === 'fly'">
    <p>Taking the train</p>
  </div>
</template>


Please clarify what I need to change to correct error #2 "mounting on app". Thanks

i updated it with the relevant information, this should solve your problem
